# How to center my copyright-text in subfooter Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, footer

After checking some topic on the forum, I come here with my question.
I am using Forest Theme from Unicon  my Wordpress, I canno't manage to center the copyright-text... sounds pretty basic, but am kind of lost between the different class and id in the css.

[sick area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjPzD.jpg)

As a CSS we have today concerning the copyright and the footer:

```
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
*/
/* Footer
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
*/
#footer {
padding: 60px 0 20px 0;
background: #ffffff;
color:#ffffff;
}

#footer a{
    color:#ffffff;
}

#footer a:hover{
    color:#ffffff;
}

 /* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
 */
 /* Copyright
 /* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
 */
#copyright {
padding: 30px 0 13px 0;
background: #333333;
color:#777777;
}

#copyright .copyright-col1{
float: center;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

 #copyright .copyright-col2{
float: center;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#copyright a { color: #999999 }
#copyright a:hover { color: #cccccc }

#copyright .copyright-text {}

#copyright .social-icons {
    float: center;
    margin: -7px 0;
}

#copyright .menu{
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: right;
}

#copyright .menu li{
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 0 0 20px;
padding: 0;
}
```

I am also not sure that #copyright is the area I should focus on, or more (see photos).

Thanks in advance

Comment: `.sixteen{text-align:center;}`

Comment: `center` is not a valid value for `float` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Float: center;` isn't a valid CSS property. Read more about what float does here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

To align text to the centre, you can use `text-align: center;`